# From sql to qlik view declare variable

Tags: sql-server

I am new to QV and am having a problem transferring this query to QV. What am I doing wrong?

```
ODBC CONNECT TO XXX);
abc:
SQL DECLARE @www INT
SET @www= ( SELECT max(Id)  FROM [].[].[] where)
SQL select *
    FROM [].[].[] 
    JOIN [].[.[] on .[] = .[]
    where [qqq] = @www
    order by rrr desc;
```

Comment: What do you mean your having problems transferring the query? Are you getting an error message? Please edit your question with a few more details.

Comment: That unmatched `[` isn't in your real query, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to solve your problem?
From what I know it's not possible to use a *SQL SET* command, because in Qlik we already have a *SET* command which is far different from the SQL one.
I would suggest to do a first query that retrieves the *max(Id)*, then pass it to a variable and then do the second query with that parameter.

i.e.

```
//execute the first query and retrieve the max Id
FirstQuery:
SQL
SELECT
    max(Id) as maxId
FROM
    schema.table;

//retrieve the value from the previous query and pass it to a variable
let vMaxId = fieldvalue('maxId', 1);

//execute the second query and use the variable in the where clause
SecondQuery:
SQL
SELECT
    *
FROM
    schema.table
WHERE
    Field = $(vMaxId);
```

Also, take a look here to know how the [FieldValue function](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/3.1/Subsystems/Hub/Content/ChartFunctions/InterRecordFunctions/fieldvalue.htm) works